# Log a body field with apache

Tags: apache, logging, server, monitor

I am using`CustomLog` to log every request into a file called monitoring.`monitoring`.

The current configurations:

```
LogFormat "%a %{%ms}T %{%s}t %m %s %U" monitoring
CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/monitoring" monitoring
```

I just wan't to log also with this field a field called `appID` for the `post/delete/put`